# Finding number of samples in a .wav header

Tags: audio, wav

The wav file has a header (44 bytes). In this header is specified the sample rate of the signal, number of channels and so on, number of samples from the audio file.
I need to know where can I find the number of samples information in the header.

What would be the formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting at the 40th byte for the next 4 bytes (little endian) is the Subchunk2 size. This can also be deduced from the formula:

```
Subchunk2size = NumSamples * NumChannels * BitsPerSample/8
```

`NumChannels` start at byte 22 and 2 bytes (little endian) in length. `BitsPerSample` start at 34th byte and is 2 bytes (little endian) in length. Replacing all these you can get the NumSamples which is the number of samples.

For example: if `Subchunksize2=2048, NumChannels=2 and BitsPerSample=16`, you get 
`2048 = NumSamples * 2 * 2` so `NumSamples=512`

A good read is [here.](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/)

Comment: To clarify: this approach will not work for all WAV files. Most WAV files are well-behaved liked this (a 44-byte header followed by the sample data), but many are not, and the WAV file format does not demand that WAV files be structured in this way.